# Linux library naming conventions: Capitalization?

Tags: linux, unix, naming-conventions, filenames

When looking at the libraries in `/usr/lib/`, one noticed that almost all `lib*.so` files aren't capitalized even if the official library name is, e.g.,

- BLAS: `libblas.so`,
- cURL: `libcurl.so`,
- BFD: `libbfd.so`.

Is there a Linux or Unix convention that prescribes having library names in lowercase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's rather an inherited culture than a convention itself. Default filenames of Unix systems are predominantly written in lowercase. That came for some historical reasons.

Some file systems are case insensitive and if you share Linux files to OSs that has case insensitive file systems you can get some conflicts.

If you have three files: *someFile.txt, SomeFile.txt, somefile.txt*

In Linux you have three files with different names, but in an OS that use HFS+ (present on MACs), VFAT, FAT32, FAT12 (present in old versions of MSDOS and Windows) you have three files with the same name (*somefile.txt*), thus you will have filename conflicts.

The C community adopt lower-case as a convention to the C-libraries. A lot of influent C programmers integrate the community that initiated the development of applications for Unix.

A last funny reason, **programmers are lazy**. Use the shift or Caps-lock key, unless it's necessary, isn't cool.